# Run task from other Task

Tags: python, django, celery

I try run task `send_request` from task `start_distribution` with `apply_async` method not work.

```
tasks.py

from celery import shared_task, group
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

from .models import Distribution, Client

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=200, default_retry_delay=30)
def send_request(self, distribution_id, client_id):
    pass


@shared_task(bind=True)
def start_distribution(self, distribution_id):

    distribution = Distribution.objects.get(pk=distribution_id)

    logger.info(f'distribution obj:')
    logger.info(f'  pk: {distribution.pk}')
    logger.info(f'  start date: {distribution.start_date}')
    logger.info(f'  end date: {distribution.end_date}')
    logger.info(f'  tag: {distribution.tag.name}')
    logger.info(f'  mobile_code : {distribution.mobile_code.mobile_code}')
    logger.info(f'  body message : {distribution.body_message}')

    clients_for_send = Client.objects.filter(
        mobile_code=distribution.mobile_code,
        tag=distribution.tag
    ).all()

    logger.info('Pk sending client:')

    [logger.info(client.pk) for client in clients_for_send]

    g = group(send_request.s(distribution_id, client.pk) for client in clients_for_send)

    g.apply_async(
        queue='external_req',
        expires=distribution.end_date
    )
```

celery.py

```
from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Notification_service.settings')

app = Celery('Notification_service',
             broker='redis://localhost/0',
             backend='redis://localhost/1'
             )

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.conf.task_queues = (
    Queue('distribution', routing_key='distribution'),
    Queue('external_service_req', routing_key='external_req')
)

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Running different workers for different queues.
For distribution queue
`celery -A NotificationService.celery worker -P prefork -l INFO -Q  distribution -n distribution`
For external_req queue
`celery -A NotificationService.celery worker -P gevent -l INFO -Q external_service_req -n external_service_req`

Log for distribution worker:

```
[2022-08-08 21:24:22,253: INFO/MainProcess] Task NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d] received
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,146: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]: distribution obj:
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,147: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]:   pk: 43                               
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,147: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]:   start date: 2022-08-08 21:25:00+00:00
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,148: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]:   end date: 2022-08-10 21:40:00+00:00  
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,151: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]:   tag: test                            
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,154: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]:   mobile_code : +5volna                
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,155: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]:   body message : Hi                    
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,156: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]: Pk sending client:                     
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,159: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]: 2                                      
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,160: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]: 3                                      
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,160: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d]: 4                                      
[2022-08-08 21:25:00,203: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task NotificationService.tasks.start_distribution[7a9f4adb-2297-44c2-b2fe-23a18594cd5d] succeeded in 0.15243399999599205s: None
```

Log for external_service_req worker:

```
[2022-08-08 21:24:12,685: INFO/MainProcess] celery@external_service_req ready.
[2022-08-08 21:24:12,690: INFO/MainProcess] pidbox: Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0.
```

First task `start_distribution` successfully completed, but group tasks `g.apply_async(queue='external_req',expires=distribution.end_date)` not get into the external_service_req queue.

Comment: What's the point of sending task from another task? Isn't it a bad idea? And why isn't it work, can you share an error or something? Also instead of `apply_async` try `delay` method, it might help you

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not work" -- do you get an error? Or what?

Comment: Have you tried running another task in the same external queue to ensure the queue is actually working?